# Rename an already-created VM in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a VM created by Vagrant which is currently in 'saved' state. I want to preserve the state, but also want to change it's name as it is becoming difficult to organize many VMs I have created by vagrant. Is there an easy way to rename them? If I just change Vagrantfile, it doesn't work (shows that the VM by the new name is 'not created'). I am slightly reluctant to change the directory names and contents manually.

Comment: What VM provider are you using, VirtualBox or VMware?

Comment: VirtualBox is my VM provider